# webService Error

Tags: c#, api, service

I am using Log Me In Rescue API to pull some reports from their web service (consumed as a web reference via Visual Studio 2010).

the report works.

However, when I try to run another report it gives me a:

```
getReport_PollRateExceeded
```

I spoke to Log Me In Rescue tech support staff, and they stated this is not an issue with their API, it's an issue with the code that i'm using.  They had no limits on the number of reports you could pull from the server (they even allow you to do it real time).

I am querying their server only once ever 30 or so seconds, so i can't possibly be going over any set limit in .NET that i can think off.

The web service API can be found here:

```
https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/API/API.asmx
```

Their Wiki is here:

```
http://logmeinwiki.com/wiki/Rescue:API
```

The code i'm using is:

```
 private void myReport_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            LMIR.getReportRet response = new LMIR.getReportRet();

            while (response.ToString() != "getReport_OK")
            {
                response = proxy.getReport(iTechID, NODE_REF.NODE, sAuthCodes, out sReports);

            }
        }
```

I do not call that worker process again, until the user REQUESTS it, i even disable the request button in favor of a progress bar, waiting for the runworkercompleted() routine to finish.

But, sure enough, if i request within that 30 second limit, i receive the pollRateExceeded.

So i'm a b it confused.

Is this something that can be fixed in the app.config file?

---

I have since created a short program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using testLMIR.LMIR;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace testLMIR
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string sUser = "";
        string sPass = "";
        int iNodeID = 74249;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LMIR.API proxy = new LMIR.API();
            proxy.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

            sUser = textBox1.Text.ToString();
            sPass = textBox2.Text.ToString();


            loginRet oLogin = proxy.login(sUser, sPass);
            Console.WriteLine(oLogin.ToString());

            string sAuthCode = "";
            requestAuthCodeRet oAuthCodeReq = proxy.requestAuthCode(sUser, sPass, out sAuthCode);

            string sReport = "";

            getReportRet oGetReport = proxy.getReport(iNodeID,NODE_REF.NODE, sAuthCode, out sReport);
            Console.WriteLine(oGetReport + "<br />");

            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            oGetReport = proxy.getReport(iNodeID, NODE_REF.NODE, sAuthCode, out sReport);
            Console.WriteLine(oGetReport + "<br />");

            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            oGetReport = proxy.getReport(iNodeID, NODE_REF.NODE, sAuthCode, out sReport);
            Console.WriteLine(oGetReport + "<br />");

            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
    }
}
```

This program will take the login from 2 text boxes on the form, and take action when the button is pressed.  Here's the results:

```
login_OK
getReport_OK<br />
getReport_PollRateExceeded<br />
getReport_PollRateExceeded<br />
```

If i'm reading this information correctly, i can see that even 30 seconds later, i still couldn't pull the report.

I highly doubt this is a limitation of the program, no?

Comment: Note, for other report functions, like requestPinCode(), if i run them after a getreport(), i also receive the 'PollRateExceeded' error.  So i am very unsure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the LMIR engineering team, the pollrateexceeded does indeed exist; you cannot request more than 1 piece of information in a 60 second period; only PinCodes will work with that.  Anything else is 1 request per minute.  No way around that, at this time.

Comment: Yup; it took me talking to a design engineer to figure out the answer.  The support staff and people in the forums, moderators, and our rep at LMIR had no clue lol

Answer (score 0):

Tight looping like that without any termination point other than success looks like a bad idea to me. What if the authentication has changed, for example? You'd hammer the service as hard as you could. I'd have a maximum retry limit if I were you. I'd also add some logging into your code, so you can see how often you *do* need to retry.

However, if the tech support staff claim that they don't have a limit, but it looks like you do, it's easy enough to find out for sure: log the traffic. Use [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) or [Fiddler](http://fiddlertool.com) to log requests and responses. If you can show that the "PollRateExceeded" error is definitely from their service, I would certainly hope they'd look into that.

I suggest you write a short program which *just* pulls the report twice, ten seconds apart. If that *does* work, then you need to work out why it doesn't work for you in your normal code. If it *doesn't* work, send them that code, which should be short and complete. Give them the network trace at the same time. It'll be hard for them to argue with that.

Comment: The sAuthCodes uses a perm authorization token that allows the user NOT to be logged into the web service to request the data.  So, authorization isn't an issue thankfully on this front, as it wont ever change.

I did consider adding a sleep in there, to let the thread wait between sending requests, but the overall result is still the same, it just gives that exceeded error.

I'll do the trace to see what's up.

Comment: @user674311: But any other potential error? If there's something wrong with your request in whatever form, do you *really* want to just keep retrying forever, without even pausing? I'm not suggesting that pausing and having a retry limit will solve this error - I'm saying it's the right thing to do *regardless* of the issue you're currently facing.

Comment: Oh no, i totally agree...This isn't 'release' code, so i havn't added all of my checks in there.  But i can check each of those variables to ensure they are what they should be. Doing the trace now, and adding some logging in code to see if those variables are changing incorrectly.

Comment: I did the logging, and noted that the variables are not changing, techID and sAuthCode remains constant sent to the worker remains accurate.  Checking wireshark log.

Comment: I edited my initial question above, with more detail.  As i can see from the short UI i built there, with nothing other than the basics right from their API, it still gives me those rate Exceededs.  I can pretty much assume, at this point, the issue is on their end, correct?

Comment: Fiddler gave me the following info:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><getReportResponse xmlns="https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/API/API.asmx"><getReportResult>getReport_PollRateExceeded</getReportResult><sReport /></getReportResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>`

To me, this means that the service itself is causing the issue.  Not my code.

Comment: @user674311: Absolutely. Hopefully they'll be able to track down what's going on.